# Multiplexing in Pi

Tags: gpio

How many inputs can raspberry pi 3 accept? I need to input 60 temp. sensors. Should I use multiple Pi, or there is some multiplexing technique available?

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on what type of sensors they are..........and I would also suggest giving some more background on your project. Why you need 60 temp sensors, how far apart are they, how often you need to take measurements ect.

Comment: Will be needing data at about intervals of 30 minutes. I need around 60 sensors for determining the temperature of a large area, essentially a floor of my office. I will place them apart, and gather their data, and use the mean value.

Comment: do you have a sensor in mind?   Might be easier/cheaper to build a car that drives around and takes readings in different locations

Comment: The purpose is to eliminate human intervention, and there are offices on every floor, the car option is not possible. Probably DS18B20 can work, but I am open to it.

Comment: maybe remote sensing would do it .... http://www.instructables.com/id/LOG-Wireless-Temperature-Monitoring/ ....... http://www.instructables.com/id/NRF24L01-Remote-Sensor-Data-Collection/

Comment: https://www.losant.com/blog/making-the-esp8266-low-powered-with-deep-sleep ............... http://homecircuits.eu/blog/battery-powered-esp8266-iot-logger/

Comment: If you are looking at a large area, and thinking of using DS18B20, then the question of whether you need a mux will come much later. DS18B20 is not design for transmitting the signal in long distance.

Answer (score 1):

MCP3208 mux ADC can handle 8 inputs.

You can use HC138 demux to select 1 of 8 MCP3208s.  So using one rpi, you can  sense 64 inputs.

Actually you can easily use just 3 gpio pins to select up to 8 HC138.

In other words, 1 rpi can select 1 of 8 HC138, each of which selects 1 of 8 MCP3208, each of which selects 1 of 8 channels, each for one sensor.

Total = 1 x 8 x 8 x 8 = 512 sensors!